# Change Action bar title for each tab swipe on android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, tabbar

I have set up Action bar with swipe tabs using ActionBarSherlock and Fragments.

I want to have different Action bar title for each tab. And it would be great if i could set up image instead of the title, so each tab would have different Action bar image title.

I would appreciate any suggestions and links to tutorials! Thanks:)

here is my code:
TabActivity.java

```
package com.tptabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class TabActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
        setContentView(mViewPager);

        final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabAdapter(this, mViewPager);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("").setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.social_group)), JoinFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("").setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.content_edit)), CreateFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("").setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location_web_site)), PlayFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("").setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.collections_collection)), ResultFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("").setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.device_access_accounts)), StoreFragment.class, null);
    }
}
```

TabAdapter.java

```
package com.tptabs;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener , ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();
    private final String TAG = "21st Polling:";

    static final class TabInfo{
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args){
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity fa, ViewPager pager) {
        super(fa.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = fa;
        mActionBar = fa.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args){
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }

    @Override
    public  void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        Log.v(TAG, "clicked");
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i<mTabs.size(); i++){
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag){
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        //Toast.makeText(mContext, "You've deselected a tab", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried mActionBar.setTitle("your current tab title") inside onPageSelected?

Comment: Thanks it works, but than i start the app it sets old title first, on swipe to any tab it changes to "your current tab title" and it stays the same. I put it inside onPageSelected in TabAdapter.java. Should i put it inside the fragment it self?

Comment: Mine was only an example . Where is the string you wan to set as actionbar title? Can you access it inside onPageSelected ?

Comment: i haven't created any string yet, in  fact i would like to use an image insted, i think it should be posible to access it inside onPageSelected.

Comment: i would like to have different action bar title image for each tab

Comment: you want an image in place of the title or you want a different image as home icon?

Comment: no icon, image instead of the title. like banner. thanks for helping me by the way, im lost.

Comment: Try with mActionBar.setIcon

Comment: it works, but how can i remove the title so i only get icon?

Comment: mActionBar.setTitle(""); removes the title and mActionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.social_group); adds the new icon.
but its the same for each tab and its not set from the begining(only sets if i swipe), any ideas?

Comment: what you want to show as first item?

Comment: image related to the first tab, and i have 5 in total. so on each tab swipe new image displayed in the action bar.

Comment: the when your app starts call mActionBar.setIcon and pass the correct value. Have it worked?

Comment: can you please look at my code and specify where i need to put it?
or do i need to set it onCreateView inside of each fragment?

Comment: after final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar(); you call bar.setIcon(): and bar.setTitle("");

Comment: thanks, i feel stupid now))) it works
but how do i set the images for the rest of the tabs?

Comment: change it when onPageSelected is fired. The images are inside the res folder?

Comment: yes they are inside the res folder.

Comment: I putted inside an answare. If you have any question comment there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener , ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
   int resId = {R.drawable.position0, R.drawable.position1, R.drawable.position2, R.drawable.position3, R.drawable.position4};

 @Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    int resIdLenght = resId.length;
    if (position < 0 || position >= resIdLenght)
            return;
    int drawableId = resId[position];
    mActionBar.setIcon(drawableId);  
}


}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to set addOnPageChangeListener to your view pager like this

```
 pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == 1) {
               setTitle("Page 1");
            } else if (position == 2)
            {
                setTitle("Page 2");
            }
            else
            {
                setTitle("Page 3");
            }


        }
```

Comment: Please, explain more about your answer.

Comment: Set this listeneer to your view pager where you set your adapter

Comment: I reviewed your answer. You should support your answer.

Comment: I am sorry , but how do i do that . I am new to stack overflow

Comment: You can edit your answer and add details to it. It's okay for now, please, do that for next time.

Comment: @Alex Do you still remember what is this setTitle() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        getActionBar().setTitle(tab.getText());//to change titile as per the current tab
        getActionBar().setIcon(tab.getIcon());//to change icon as per the current tab

    }
```